# How do you structure the http calls inside your'e Angular2+ project's?

Tags: angular

I want to avoid mixing the API calls with other logic inside my services.
I was wondering how you guys structuring yours API calls,

Are you creating a service where you are keeping all the API calls of the entire application?

Are you creating a HTTP folder and adding separately file's with the API calls of each module?

Or are you just keeping it inside the services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were having a provider(services) folder for each module(single component or multiple), but we want to isolate module as much as possible for ex: our old structure was

- modules

  - registration

    - components
    - store(we use redux)

      - providers => to access the store
    - providers

Then we got issues with need to access some data from the store form a different module. Then it introduced module dependancy and became a pain and it became a kind of mess honestly, we had hard time to define the responsibility for some services or the store. So module isolation with providers didn't work well. Then we decided to separate the http calls and the store access from the modules.

Now we trying to use below structure so far working well, with the time we are transforming old modules to new structure(takes sometime).

- entities (responsible for http calls and store populating and access)

  - providers => http providers
  - store

    - providers
- modules

  - registration

    - components

I dont think there is a blue pill for each type of the project. Usually when project grow you understand something is wrong :) and try to find to have as much less mess as possible. It's a kind of ongoing process. 
Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes we are keeping the http calls in service files.We have different controllers in our backend application, so we will be creating seperate serivce file for each controller.Authentication related calls are added under a single service file.